# Strict standards error on joomla template installation

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to install a joomla template but i get the following error

```
( ! ) Strict standards: Declaration of RokInstaller::getInstance() should be compatible with JInstaller::getInstance($basepath = 'C:\wamp\ww...', $classprefix = 'JInstaller...', $adapterfolder = 'adapter') in C:\wamp\www\Joomla\tmp\install_55d4bc62ca9d1\business001_final\installer\RokInstaller.php on line 365
```

I have joomla 3.4.3, can someone help me get pass this issue please.

Thanks for all your help guys

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using

Comment: Strict standards aren't really a major issue. Please Google strict errors and also contact the Rockettheme developers

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the reporting of STRICT Warnings by editing `php.ini` and changing the parameter `error_reporting`

Use the wampmanager menu to make sure you edit the correct `php.ini` file

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Find this line

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and change it to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```